# UserReport and Turbolinks - How to make JS turbolinks compatible?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm running rails, and I've got this code at end of my body tag.

```
:javascript
  var _urq = _urq || [];
  _urq.push(['initSite', 'mySiteId']);
  (function() {
  var ur = document.createElement('script'); ur.type = 'text/javascript'; ur.async = true;
  ur.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://cdn.userreport.com/userreport.js' : 'http://cdn.userreport.com/userreport.js');
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ur, s);
  })();
```

No matter what I do, clicking any and all turbolink enabled links breaks this code. The button disappears.

I've tried encapsulating the code inside a function called userReport, and then doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(userReport);
$(document).on('page:load', userReport);
```

This does not work.

Suggestions are very welcome :)

Comment: That should work, are you sure your `userReport` function works?

Comment: remove //require turbolinks in app.js and install jquery turblinks

Answer (score 2):

Your script at the end of the body section, just inserts `script` element into html's `head` section every time the `body` is reloaded. I wonder, why do you need to do it this way? Because, every time one clicks a link, you'll get a duplicate `script` element in doc's `head` section (thanks to turbolink’s magic). This may be the reason of your problem.

If you really need to do this by javascript, try to add your code at the end of app/assets/javascript/application.js  (it’s not recommended,  I know, but just to test the idea).
Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**
According to [UserReport's docs](https://userreport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202510588-Installing-UserReport-script-on-website) the javascript snippet should belong to the `head` section. To do it the same way, as it's shown in their example you could place the script inside a ‘userreport’ partial and use that partial inside app’s layout template:

```
<head>
  …
  <%= render 'layots/userreport' %>
</head>
```

Comment: Good point! Just re-inserting will not work and insert duplicate scripts, as you say. He should find a way to re-trigger the script from userreport.com. I would say: ask support from userreport, or disable turbolinks ;)

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty for the efforts, even though I still haven't found a way to have both UserReport and Turbolinks working at the same time =/
It's such a pity I had to turn on Turbolinks just to enable UserReport.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the userreport.js script does not enable a "reloading" of the widget, so this is not possible.

I extracted the code from the CDN, modified it and use it in my assets so that i can call `reset_user_report();` whenever I want to show the widget, (see this repo : https://github.com/nicolasmlv/userreport-turbolinks)

Use at your own risk because it will not use anymore the userreport cdn (features updates / bug fixing)